# Play .pls on windows phone 7.1

Tags: wpf, windows-phone-7, wpf-controls, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone

I have a problem playing .pls live streaming channel on windows phone 7 media element. i asked this question before as well and someone said that you need to parse the address inside .pls becuase .pls is a playlist format and you have link to play audio inside it but when i parse: 
**http:// 69.175.103.226:8540/listen.pls** i get **http:// 69.175.103.226:8540**
you can check this by typing this on browser **http:// 69.175.103.226:8540/listen.pls** and download .pls and open with notepad and it is not being played by windows phone

any idea how to do this? kindly help me i am stuck

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell it is a 48kbps MP3 stream. I don't see why it wouldn't work unless you do something wrong with the way you are setting the media source.

Should be:

```
mediaElement.Source = new Uri("URL_TO_STREAM",UriKind.Absolute);
mediaElement.Play();
```